# weak symbol attributes and extern declarations

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linker, weak-symbol

Here is some ARM assembly code compiled with GCC.

Snippet from `startup.s`:

```
    .globl  Default_Handler
    .type   Default_Handler, %function
Default_Handler:
     B       .
    .size   Default_Handler, . - Default_Handler

    .macro  IRQ handler
    .weak   \handler
    .set    \handler, Default_Handler
    .endm

IRQ  POWER_CLOCK_IRQHandler
```

In `file1.c`

```
void POWER_CLOCK_IRQHandler(void)
{
        //Do some things...
}
```

In this code, `POWER_CLOCK_IRQHandler` is a weak symbol. When the code runs, code from `file1` is executed.

Now I define `Default_Handler` in another file and I comment out its definition in `startup.s`.

```
.globl  Default_Handler
.type   Default_Handler, %function
//Default_Handler:
//    B       .
    .size   Default_Handler, . - Default_Handler

    .macro  IRQ handler
    .weak   \handler
    .set    \handler, Default_Handler
    .endm

    IRQ  POWER_CLOCK_IRQHandler
```

In file 3:

```
void Default_Handler(void)
{
    //Do some other things
}
```

If I write the definition of `Default_Handler` in another file or I declare `Default_Handler` as weak, `POWER_CLOCK_IRQHandler` will be linked against `Default_Handler`. The linker misses the weak attribute and does not link it against `POWER_CLOCK_IRQHandler` in `file1.c`, it just tried to resolve the expression given in `.set`.

Can someone explain what occurs precisely?
What is the proper solution to keep weak attribute effective on `POWER_CLOCK_IRQHandler` when the `Default_Handler` implementation is in another file than `startup.s`?